# why segmentation fault? strtok and malloc

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, malloc, strtok

I have the following code which works perfectly when not using `malloc`, but when I want to add in dynamic memory allocation it says segmentation fault although it compiles without warnings or errors. Why?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNUM 30
#define STR 200 
#define MAXLEN 40

struct human { //Va
    char name[MAXLEN];
    char surname[MAXLEN];   
    int age;
    float weight;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    char *dlim= ",", *end = "\n", *stop = NULL;
    char *tok, *string;
    string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * STR);
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    struct human man[MAXNUM];

    FILE *fin = fopen("data.txt", "r"); 

    if (string == NULL) {
        printf("Memory not allocated");
    }

    if (fin == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(string, sizeof(string), fin)) {
        tok = strtok(string, dlim);
        strcpy(man[i].name, tok);

        tok = strtok(stop, dlim);
        strcpy(man[i].surname,tok);         

        tok = strtok(stop, dlim);
        man[i].age = atoi(tok);

        tok = strtok(stop, dlim);
        man[i].weight = atof(tok);

        i++;
    }
    fclose(fin);  
    free(string);

    j = i;
    i = 0;
    while (i < j) {
        printf("%s %s %d %f \n", man[i].name, man[i].surname, man[i].age, man[i].weight);   
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(string)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `fgets(string, sizeof(string), fin)` --> `fgets(string, STR, fin)`  : `sizeof(string)` is `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you so much. Is this because sizeof(string) is actually completely unknown at that point?

Comment: no, pointer size 4 or 8 or etc. but already known.

Comment: @stellarhawk34 `string` is a pointer, so its size is probably 4, unless you are on a 64-bit machine, and then it is likely to be 8. The `sizeof()` operator has nothing to do with the length of the character string that `string` point to. For that, you should use `strlen()`.

Comment: @Logicrat: Unfortunately, calling `strlen()` on the pointer returned by `malloc()` reads indeterminate values, which means undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make `string` an allocated array of `char`, `sizeof(string)` no longer gives you the size of the array, it gives you the size of the pointer.  Therefore you must change the loop to tell `fgets` the size of your array:

```
while (fgets(string, STR, fin)) {
    ...
```

Or better, if you reallocate the array to size `size`:

```
while (fgets(string, size, fin)) {
    ...
```